# ES6 Promise patterns for exotic control flows

Tags: callback, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

ES6 Promises are great. So far it’s been pretty easy to adjust my thinking from
the callback idiom. I’ve found it naturally encourages more modular code, and of
course error handling is much clearer.

But a few times I’ve encountered flow situations that don’t seem(?) like they
can be readily translated from nodebacks to promises (and perhaps that’s just that, but maybe I’m just blind to the answers). Since promises are agnostic
about the next operation (or if there even is one), it seems pretty tough to use
Promises with APIs that don’t just take callbacks, but also *return* them.

The most common example that comes to mind is the ‘done’ callback. It shows up in things like database connections to signify ‘return connection to pool’ but I’ve seen it pop up in plenty of other places, too.

```
function getSomeStupidConnection(cb) {
    var conn = /* ... */;
    var iNeedToBeToldWhenIAmDone = function() { /* ... */ };

    cb(conn, iNeedToBeToldWhenIAmDone);
}

getSomeStupidConnection(function(conn, done) {
    /* ... */

    conn.doLotsOfStuff(function(soMuchStuff) {

        /* stuff! so much fun! */

        /* okay conn go away I’m tired */

        done();
    });
});
```

Flow-reversal like this is obviously not something you want to have in your APIs
to start with, but it’s out there and you can’t really avoid it sometimes. With
callbacks, you can pass the ‘call later’ inner callback to the original ‘outer’
callback. It doesn’t exactly lead to a clean seperation of concerns, but at
least it’s quick and simple.

Is there a Promise-based approach suited to situations like this? A way to say,
‘here’s the resolve value -- but when the chain is complete, also do this’? I
suspect there’s nothing that perfectly matches what I just described because it
isn’t really possible to say a chain is ‘done’, but maybe I’m missing some
pattern that gets you close to that without making a mess...

---

Edit: Based on the feedback so far I've realized that there's simply no way to wrap such an API in true promises, because the promise you return will never be able to tell you anything about any subsequent chained promises that piggyback on it. But you *can* fake it. The twist is that the result is rather brittle; it must assume that the only `then` which needs the connection object is the one which immediately follows. The consumer of the promise would need to understand that it’s a one-time-use connection, which isn’t otherwise obvious. Therefore I don't really recommend it in practice, but for the sake of curiosity here is a solution that hides the `done` while behaving as (and ultimately becoming) a promise chain:

```
/* jshint node: true, esnext: true */
'use strict';

// Assume this comes from an external library. It returns a connection and a
// callback to signal that you are finished with the connection.

function getConnectionExternal(cb) {
    let connection = 'Received connection.';
    let done = () => console.log('Done was called.');

    cb(null, connection, done);
}

// Our promisey wrapper for the above

function getConnection() {
    let _done;

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getConnectionExternal((err, connection, done) => {

            if (err) return reject(err);

            _done = (val) => {
                done();
                return val;
            };

            resolve(connection);
        });
    });

    let _then = promise.then.bind(promise);

    promise.then = (handler) => _then(handler).then(_done, _done);

    return promise;
}

// Test it out

getConnection()
    .then(connection => {
        console.log(connection);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('Finished using connection!');
                resolve('This should be after connection closes.');
            }, 200);
        });
    })
    .then(msg => console.log(msg))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Console prints:

- Received connection.
- Finished using connection!
- Done was called.
- This should be after connection closes.

Comment: Not with ES6-Promises, but more powerful libraries typically provide `.finally()`-methods which would be just what you need here. Also have a look at how [Bluebird manages resources](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#resource-management).

Comment: Love your method names :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A way to say, ‘here’s the resolve value -- but when the chain is complete, also do this’?

No, native promises do not provide such a facility. I would go with a resource function that takes a promise-returning callback, the callback does everything (in a chain) that needs to be done while the connection is open. Instead of passing `iNeedToBeTold` to the callback, the resource manager function observes the promise and does what needs to be done when it resolves.

```
function manageConnection(cb) {
    return getSomeConnection(…) // get the connections asynchronously - via a promise of course
    .then(function(conn) {
        function whenDone() {
            … // do what needs to be done
            return result;
        }
        var result = cb(conn);
        return result.then(whenDone, whenDone);
    });
}

manageConnection(function(conn) {
    return conn.doLotsOfStuff(soMuch)
    .then(function(stuff) {
        /* stuff! so much fun! */
    });
}).then(…)
```

Comment: Interesting, Bergi. This is probably the cleanest approach without using a specialized library -- promises for everything except one callback to manage the odd case.

Comment: Bergi, you may be interested in the edit I made to the question. Your answer stands as correct, but I did successfully devise a (dubiously useful) way to provide a promisey API that handles the done callback in the background.

Comment: Hm, that looks rather dubious to me. Of course you can always hide the `manageConnection` thing in a function that returns an object with a `then` method that does all the work, but that just works in an *unexpected* way when someone looks at the chain. It's a neat little trick, but I would never use this. Btw, your `_done` is not called when the `handler` fails.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I qualified it as a curiosity / not recommended. I repaired the _done bit you mentioned, but it still depends on too much 'going right' of course.

Comment: Also known as "the disposer pattern", this is like "using" in c#, "with" in Python or try with resource in Java.

Comment: Your "whenDone" suppresses errors, please consider changing it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: No, `whenDone` is supposed to always return the (possibly rejected) `result` promise and doesn't suppress its errors?

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Bergi's solution, this is called the disposer pattern. It exists in many forms in many languages - `with` in Python, `using` in C# and `try(){` with resource in Java. Some languages handle resource in scopes this way natively through destructurs like C#.

The general idea is for a scope to encapsulate the life-time of a value. In your case a database connection. It's a lot tidier than having to call `done` in a callback since it's much easier to forget to call `done` which leaves an open connection and a resource leak. Synchronously it'd look like:

```
function scope(cb){
     try{ 
         var conn = getConnection(...);
         return cb(conn);
     } finally {
         conn.release();
     }
}
```

The promises version is not too different:

```
function conn(data){
    var _connection;
    return getConnection().then(function(connection){
        _connection = connection; // keep a reference
        return data(_connection); // pass it to the function
    }).then(function(val){
         // release and forward
         _connection.release(); // if release is async - chain
         return val; 
    }, function(err){
         _connection.release();
         throw err; // forward error
    });
});
```

Which would use:

```
conn(function(db){
    return db.query("SELECT * FROM ...");
}).then(function(result){ // handle result
    // connection is released here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very elegant when presented this way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a done() function is that people forget to call it, causing leaks.

I like Bergi's answer with the passed-in callback because it is clean, but it is not very "promise-y", and still open-endedly unsafe, e.g. if people chain in promises that never resolve the callback-promise, then it stalls and leaks.

This is a problem being discussed in browser APIs as well, and one pattern we're pondering is to return an

### [AutoClosingPromise](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.webapi/Q1Y0cqwdEW4/AzBKLzYn7u4J)

An AutoClosingPromise acts like a promise but does two things differently:

1. It "closes a ticket" (calls done) *after* executing its .then().
2. Additionally, when it subsumes another promise, if it sees another AutoClosingPromise returned from its .then(), then it forwards it out (passes that promise's ticket - a different ticket - out to the AutoClosingPromise it returned from its own .then() function).

The first part means that an API can return an AutoClosingPromise with a "ticket" that holds a resource open (like an open-count) and be assured that the ticket will be closed once the first .then() function returns.

The second part lets a caller make additional asynchronous calls on the API from within the immediate .then() function, letting the API keep the resource open for as long as tickets overlap in time.

A feature of this is that resources are not tendered across regular promises, only AutoClosing ones, avoiding risk of leaks. For example:

```
var lock = new ExampleLock();
lock.access("foo")
.then(() => lock.set("foo1"))
.then(() => lock.set("foo2"))
.then(() => lock.set("foo3"))
.then(() => {})
.then(() => lock.set("foo4"))
.catch(failed);
```

would extend the resource (the lock) to the first three, but not the fourth:

```
setting foo1 [LOCKED]
setting foo2 [LOCKED]
setting foo3 [LOCKED]
setting foo4 [UNLOCKED]
```

Here's the code:

```
function AutoClosingPromise(ticket, p) {
  this.pending = true;
  this.ticket = ticket;

  var close = result => {
    this.pending = false;
    if (this.ticket) {
      this.ticket.close();
      if (result && result.handoffTicket && this.returnedThenPromise) {
        // callback returned an AutoClosingPromise! Forward its ticket
        this.returnedThenPromise.takeTicket(result.handoffTicket());
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
  this.p = p.then(v => close(this.success && this.success(v)),
                  r => close(this.failure && this.failure(r)));
}
AutoClosingPromise.prototype = {
  then: function(success, failure) {
    if (this.pending && !this.success && !this.failure) {
      this.success = success;
      this.failure = failure;
      this.returnedThenPromise = new AutoClosingPromise(null, this.p);
      return this.returnedThenPromise;
    } else {
      return this.p.then(success, failure);
    }
  },
  takeTicket: function(ticket) { this.ticket = ticket; },
  handoffTicket: function() {
    var ticket = this.ticket;
    this.ticket = null;
    return ticket;
  }
};
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/w0ufvahL (needs a browser that understands es6 arrow functions, like Firefox, e.g. not Chrome).

Since the API controls all asynchronous calls that issue tickets, this should be fairly leak-proof. E.g. even if a caller ignores the promise returned from the API entirely, close is still called.

Note that this is a fairly new idea rather than a proven construct, so if you end up using it, please let me know how it works. ;-)

Comment: Oh, I don't think my approach is not promise-y - it's a very declarative wrapper just like try-finally - but I might be biased :-) I don't think there's any good way to counter forever-pending promises but an explicit timeout - your AutoClosingPromise doesn't seem to handle them either. Some other things I don't like about that pattern: It violates the promise contract for multiple or delayed `then` calls, and I'm not sure how well it composes for multiple acquired ressources with different tickets.

Comment: AutoClosingPromise prevents a forever-pending promise from holding a resource open by not holding resources open across plain promises. A resource is only held open over the *synchronous* .then() callback, plus over any new asynchronous calls **on the API** initiated inside that callback. So the API never waits on anything asynchronous outside of its control, and clients can't cause a leak.

Comment: As for the promise-contract, this is not a general promise, but a stricter contract. Extending the class to support multiple .then() calls seems doable, but I'll leave that to someone who needs that functionality. As for delayed .then(), it doesn't violate them, instead it purposely doesn't hold the resource open for them either, as that would leak. You don't want resources held forever open just in case someone adds a .then() later. ;-)

Comment: Oh, I'm beginning to grasp :-) I thought that I could game it by returning a `new AutoClosingPromise(null, Promise.never)` from the `then` callback, but that will only get *my own ticket* never closed. I still don't like that tickets need to implement counters themselves when they want to support holding the ressource open, but I guess that can be solved easily. A very interesting idea, to call `close()` immediately on resolution after all callbacks had been executed. I think I'm going to implement this pattern in my own promise library, +1!

Comment: Another problem is that they don't compose as easy. For example, `Promise.all([openFile("toread"), openFile("towrite")]).then([read, write] => read.pipe(write); )`. How could `all` be implemented so that it holds onto both ressources and not only the one resolving later?

Comment: Again a feature. If they composed then they'd risk leaking again, unless all the promises in the array were AutoClosing ones from the same api. You could write an .all method I suppose that checked that, but I had discrete access in mind for this.

Comment: Yeah, probably one would need to implement some kind of explicit leak management in `AutoClosingPromise.all`. Not saying it's a bug, just a problem that a solution needs to be found for :-)

Comment: Either I don't understand this approach fundamentally or this is inherently susceptible to timing issues or do you only allow a single consumer for the promise (no multiple `then`s)? If you do - it's not a promise - it's a [task](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor).

Comment: Having read this again - this is definitely not a promise but what Kris calls a "task" - these have very interesting semantics themselves (single consumer) and better simulate actual function calls, it's possible to cleanly do with them things that are impossible to do with promises (like actual cancellation). I don't think this is a viable solution to OP's problem at all but I think it's very interesting nontheless - if you have a working implementation that interops with Promises/A+ correctly let me know :) https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor/blob/master/task.js please post an issue on gtor.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, not a task, since unlike that pattern, there's no inherent reason AutoClosingPromise can't support multiple .then()s, I just left it out to keep things simple. Why would it matter how many things happen next, as long as the ticket is closed after all of them? What timing issue with multiple consumers? OP accepted Bergi's "disposer" pattern, and I see this as a challenger to that pattern, so hopefully we're all solving the same thing. I may have missed something, but with its narrow scope, I hope no interop problems. Lets see how Bergi's promise library works out. ;)

Comment: @jib When is 'after'? You can add `.then` handlers after a long time (a month later for example) - without an indication of when the last `then` was added and executed how do you know when to close the connection?

Comment: The jsfiddle can be modified, try it out. ;) The *ticket* is closed when the asynchronous operation that returns it completes, right after whatever .then() handlers that have been added up to that point are (synchronously) called. It reverts to acting like a regular promise after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are getting at, but perhaps this is what you after? Essentially nested promises...

```
let connection = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    window.setTimeout(resolve("There"), 5000);
  })
}

let connectionManager = function(){
  return connection().then(function(value){
    console.log("Hello");

    return value;
  });
}

connectionManager().then(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

[Here it is on Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20connection%20%3D%20function()%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve%2C%20reject)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20window.setTimeout(resolve(%22There%22)%2C%205000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20connectionManager%20%3D%20function()%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20connection().then(function(value)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AconnectionManager().then(function(value)%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(value)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

If you are trying to wrap existing asynchronous functionality with promises, this example here might be of help as well: http://www.2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html#example%3A_promisifying_xmlhttprequest

Depending on what nesting requirements you need, you may want to resolve a promise with a promise object; feel free to comment if you need some clarification :)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I refer to. This is nesting in the sense that the final line doesn’t show the ‘then’ that’s implicitly part of the chain because of the content of connectionManager. But the chain is still a totally linear flow, excepting short circuits caused by rejections, as far as I can tell. It may be that there's just no sensible approach to this with promises, admittedly.

Comment: @Semicolon Hmm, yeah, I'm still not sure of what kind of a workflow you are after either :S I'm sure you've explored most of the options, but if it is multiple promises you are waiting on that need to be called at different point of the chain, you may want to look at playing with `Promise.all()` and passing the unresolved promise objects down the chain. Or if you had a specific workflow you wanted to promisify, that would help too :)

Comment: Wait, Andrew, I think you're onto something very clever with Promise.all. I'm going to test this out -- I have a feeling it's possible to achieve this behavior with nothing but native Promise methods by using Promise.all.

Comment: That was a wishful red herring -- I wasn't considering the fact that the 'chain' is an abstract concept only, and that if the layer hiding the non-promisey behavior of the "done"-needing API returns a real promise, it simply can never know about *future* promises appended to that promise, period.