# Control Promise Execution Order

Tags: javascript, promise

I was having a lot of fun using promises to build a highly interactive UI. However, I ran into a tricky situation. I have a function returning a promise that executes a server update. I want to use the follow-on promise handlers to update the client side model and then issue an update event to the UI. Here is my code:

```
function updateServer (action) {
    return $.post(URL, { action: action })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

 // An example action that might affect the server
_this.freeze = function (mode) {
    updateServer("freeze").done(function (data) {
        _this.model.data.status = data.status;
    })
    .done(function () {
        $(window).trigger(Events.UpdateUI);
    });
};
```

You'll notice that I have to issue the update event in the freeze command. I'd prefer to do so inside the updateServer function in order to avoid duplicating the code in each control method.

I figured out a way to do this by passing the model updating function as a parameter to updateServer, however, it seems to violate the spirit of promises I think:

```
function updateServer (action, fn) {
    return $.post(URL, { action: action })
        .done(fn)
        .done(function () {
            $(window).trigger(Events.UpdateUI);
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

 // An example action that might affect the server
_this.freeze = function (mode) {
    updateServer("freeze", function (data) {
        _this.model.data.status = data.status;
    });
};
```

I think that another way to do that would be to devise some kind of done handler that had a lower priority, and in that way it would enable me to maintain the spirit of promise compostability. Am I missing something, or am I doing this the "right way"?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is "modifyTasks" a nom de plume of "updateServer"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I updated the code to simplify it and forgot to update the narrative.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be trying to update your UI inside a function that is intended for communicating with your server. That's the antithesis of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

If you want a way to ensure that these tasks are always executed together, you can create another function that joins these two actions together and returns the promise so that it can be chained further.

**Edit:** From your comments, it's now clear that you want to keep the data retrieval and UI update together as a unit, but perform another action *between* them. In that case, then I'd say the solution is to pass in a function. That's still consistent with the spirit of promises as long as you're not using callbacks to control your whole execution flow:

```
function updateServer (action) {
    return $.post(URL, { action: action })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function updateUI () {
    $(window).trigger(Events.UpdateUI);
}   

function updateServerAndRefreshUI (action, updateModel) {
    return updateServer(action)
    .done(updateModel)
    .done(updateUI);
}

 // An example action that might affect the server
_this.freeze = function (mode) {
    updateServerAndRefreshUI("freeze", function (data) {
        _this.model.data.status = data.status;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think you may have a point with the separation of concerns, but I think this answer has the same problem as the original situation. The UI update will occur before the model updates.

Comment: @SapphireSun I see. I hadn't realized that you needed to update the model before updating the UI. In that case I would say that passing in a function is your best bet. That's pretty much what you need to do when you want to insert some behavior in the midst of some other behavior. I wouldn't say that this violates the spirit of promises. It's subtly different from the kind of callbacks that promises are intended to eliminate because you're not using callbacks to control your entire execution flow.

Comment: @SapphireSun But on that note, jQuery's promises [_do_ violate the spirit of promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/), so I suggest getting your hands on a proper promise library like Q or bluebird if you plan on using promises to a substantial extent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use a helper function that wraps your entire action:

```
function updateUIwith(result) {
    return result.then(function() {
        $(window).trigger(Events.UpdateUI);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Now you only need to write

```
function updateServer(action) {
    return $.post(URL, {action: action})
}

// An example action that might affect the server
_this.freeze = function(mode) {
    updateUIwith(updateServer("freeze").then(function(data) {
        _this.model.data.status = data.status;
    }));
};
```

Comment: I think it's nicer to have it take a function and not a promise, effectively making it a disposer pattern.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, that would've been the other choice. JLRishe's answer is very close to that.

Comment: Fair enough. I've made a canonical about the disposer pattern by the way - if you feel like adding your own answer explaining it from a different perspective (like you did in the deferred antipattern question) I'd appreciate it :) I can see the merit in this approach.

Comment: Oh nice, I've added it to my quicklink list of faq/duplicate target questions :-) I don't see much too add though… Maybe if we'd make the question more generic about "ressource management" I could add another answer with that [AutoClosingPromise approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860929/1048572) which I find very *promising*.

Comment: Any chance to get that list? I keep searching and the autocomplete in SO's "close duplicate" dialog _never_ finds what I'm looking for. I'll read that AutoClosingPromise approach - not sure I understand how it works yet but in either case feel free to write another answer :)